# Как прописывать пути к подключаемым файлам?

Tags: файловая-система, пути

Представим есть папка "project". В ней ещё три папки такие как "HTML", "CSS" и "javaScript". В папке "HTML" есть файл index.html , а в папке "javaScript" есть файл code.js. Что надо написать в(index.html) атрибуте "src" тега "script" чтобы подключить файл code.js? Или так нельзя делать и нужно чтобы было так: папка с файлом index.html в которой папка с файлом code.js

Comment: `../javaScript/code.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в файле `index.html` подключить файл `code.js` из папки javaScript, укажите относительный путь к файлу:

```
<script src="../javaScript/code.js"></script>
```

Вы можете подключить сам скрипт как угодно, главное чтобы путь, указанный к нему, был правильным. Про абсолютные и относительные пути рекомендую [почитать тут](http://www.uamedwed.com/blog/web/absolyutnyj-i-otnositelnyj-put-k-fajlam.html).